# how do you do the equivalent of Excel's AND() and OR() operations in R?

Tags: r, boolean-logic

> drives_DF$block_device == ""
> [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE

How do I reduce this down to a single FALSE like doing an AND() in Excel?

How do I reduce this down to a single TRUE like doing an OR() in Excel?

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping your code with `all()` will return TRUE if all evaluated elements are TRUE

```
all(drives_DF$block_device == "")
[1] FALSE
```

Wrapping your code with `any()` will return TRUE if at least one of the evaluated elements is TRUE

```
any(drives_DF$block_device == "")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was bang my head against a wall for several hours.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any` and `all` functions available in R to get the required like this:

```
#Considering a vector of boolean values
boolVector =  c(F,T,F,T,F)
print(all(boolVector, na.rm = FALSE)) #AND OPERATION
print(any(boolVector, na.rm = FALSE)) #OR OPERATION
```

The output of the print statements are:

```
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
```